# Is there a compact manifold having Euler characteristic 0 which cannot be given a Lie group structure?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups

I realized that a (compact) Lie group must have Euler characteristic 0 due to Poincare-Hopf index theorem. Now I'm thinking of its converse. 
**Is there a compact manifold having Euler characteristic 0 which cannot be given a Lie group structure?**

Comment: For your first statement, you need the hypothesis that the Lie group has positive dimension or else a finite discrete group is a counterexample.

Comment: There are a lot of topological obstructions to a Lie group structure on the manifold $X$, even assuming compactness and connectedness: $\pi_2 X$ must vanish, $\pi_3 X$ must be torsion-free, $T^*X$ must be trivial, etc.  (The first two are nontrivial to prove; the latter is almost immediate but harder to check.)

Comment: Also you should assume that your manifolds are closed (since a Lie group has no boundary) and connected (since the connected components of a Lie group are diffeomorphic, and the identity component is still a Lie group), or else there are silly counterexamples.

Comment: Note that every closed odd-dimensional manifold has vanishing Euler characteristic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, lots. There are plenty of other obstructions to having a Lie group structure: for example, the fundamental group must be abelian (by the Eckmann-Hilton argument), and the rational cohomology must be an exterior algebra on odd generators (this is due to Hopf).

In particular, every closed $3$-manifold has Euler characteristic $0$, but most of them, such as $S^1 \times \Sigma_g, g \ge 2$, have both nonabelian fundamental group and cohomology that is not an exterior algebra.

Comment: You might further ask for examples where the fundamental group is abelian and the rational cohomology is an exterior algebra on odd generators (which already implies that that the Euler characteristic is $0$). You can take most of the odd spheres here; all of them satisfy these conditions but it's known that among them only $S^1$ and $S^3$ are Lie groups.

Comment: @Joe: right. Another class of obstructions comes from characteristic classes: namely, since the tangent bundle is trivializable as you say, all characteristic classes vanish. (But note that this is not enough to rule out the odd-dimensional spheres other than $S^1$ and $S^3$.)

Comment: Lie groups are parallelizable. This means that the tangent bundle has n linearly independent non-zero vector fields. But zero Euler characteristic only means that the tangent bundle has at least one non-zero vector field. The Cartesian product of an n dimensional  manifold of odd Euler characteristic with a circle has zero Euler characteristic and no more than one independent non-zero vector field, this because its n'th Stiefel- Whitney class is not zero. –  Joe S 10 mins ago   edit

Comment: You are right that one can not rule out odd dimensional spheres by looking at the characteristic classes of the tangent bundle. But one can rule out all except S1 S3 and S7 by looking at the characteristic classes of other vector bundles over spheres. The theorem is that if $S^n$ has a vector bundle whose n'th Stiefel-Whitney class is not zero, then the only possible dimensions of the sphere are 1 2 4 and 8. This implies that the only possible parallelizable spheres and the only spheres with a product are S1 S3 and S7.